# RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice

Tags: python, discord.py

Estoy trabajando con discord.py y pues, quería subir mi bot a una vps, pero cuando voy a correr el bot me sale el siguiente error: `RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice`.
Me fijé bien en las dependencias del bot y pues ahí tenía la carpeta PyNaCl, pero no era en si el paquete, así que lo instalé por consola y lo subí a la vps para ver si ya no me generaba error, pero sigue saliendo. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: No se muy bien a que te refieres exactamente con "lo instalé por consola y lo subí a la vps" pero ten en cuenta que PyNaCl es un binding de libsodium y por tanto no es código Python puro y por tanto portable, incluye librerías en C que han de ser compiladas o deben venir compiladas para el sistema operativo y arquitectura dónde van a ser ejecutados, en tu caso el servidor.

Comment: Cuando dije que lo instalé me refería que lo instalé en mi pc, luego busqué lo que me dio que fue una carpeta PyNaCl-1.3.0.dist-info y una carpeta nacl. Y luego esas carpetas las subí a la vps para que las tenga como dependencias. Pero no funcionó el bot.

Comment: Por lo que comentas es probable que se esté usando Linux. Asegurate de instalar `libffi-dev` y `python-dev`: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py#optional-packages

Answer (score -1):

El problema puede ser de la vps o donde sale la información de tú bot por ejemplo en discord.js seria `config.json` tendrías qué añadir ahí la información.

Saludos.